# Problem with sendto when sending multiple times (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

I am attempting to send a message to all the neighbouring nodes in a network and have the following loop running.

However, the network throws an error - File "Send.py", in

```
 sent = sock.sendto(data.serialize(), (destinationIp, 5000))
```

socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

```
for node in nodes:
    destinationIp = node.ip

    data = constructPacket()
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    sent = sock.sendto(data.serialize(), (destinationIp, 5000))
    sock.close()
```

Could someone please give me an idea of why this might be happening? I have double checked the ips being used and they are legitimate.

Answer (score 2):

First, do not create a socket during each iteration, for best practice try this approach:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
for node in nodes:
    destinationIp = node.ip
    data = constructPacket()
    sent = sock.sendto(data.serialize(), (destinationIp, 5000))
sock.close()
```

Second, check that `node.ip` returns a valid IP address (`socket.gaierror` means invalid hostname).